# HTTP Live Streaming in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am using `MPMoviePlayerController` to stream http video files from web. 
But am getting error and the video is not streaming.

Can I get any help for this?

```
-(IBAction)play
{    
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><title>HTTP Live Streaming Example</title></head><body><video src=http link"];     

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlString];
    _mpMoviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlaybackDidFinish:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:_mpMoviePlayer];

    [self.view addSubview:_mpMoviePlayer.view];

    [_mpMoviePlayer release];

}
```

This is my code and I am not able to get the streaming video.

Comment: Which server are you using for this?